# Java/Android scientific number to html

Tags: java, android, html, double, spannable

I'm a newbie at programming and maybe there is a solution to this problem I just don't know about. I have a TextView with values. As some of the values are really small they are shown as scientific numbers. But I don't like the 2e-02 expression I'd like to convert it to an Spannable which looks like 2*10<sup>-2</sup>. Is there an easy (already implemented way) or do I have to do a loop to count the number of decimal places (all my numbers are << 1) to create a html string?

It is just a question out of curiosity because I'm unable to find anything about this neither in books nor online. I don't have problems actually writing the function itself.

Comment: Would it be easier to take the `2e-3` expression and parse it yourself?  Ae-B => A*10[sup]B[/sup]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your numbers are formatted like that, here’s how I would do it:

```
scientific.replace(/(.*)e-0*(.*)/, "$1 &times; 10<sup>&minus;$2</sup>")
```

Comment: Yeah I did it your way, but I changed the regex a bit. Here is what I did: `String string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(index)); string = string.toLowerCase(); string = string.replaceFirst("(.*)e(.*)", "$1 &times <sup>$2</sup>"); textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(string));` I guess I have to read up about reg expressions. I never even thought about them.